# Activate Personal Hotspot with AppleScript (on a Mac)

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, applescript, applescript-objc

On a Mac, how do I activate the "Personal Hotspot" feature using a script?

These are the steps I need to take without the script:

- *(have your iPhone near you, connected to your Apple ID)*
- *(have your Mac/MacBook logged into the same AppleID)*

.

1. click the WiFi-Icon on the menu bar
2. wait a few seconds until your iPhone appears as a WiFi network
3. select this WiFi network
4. wait for the WiFi icon to change

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Long time ago, it was possible using "Apple80211.framework/Resources/airport" in a shell command, but Apple has removed the relevant option (command still exists, but no longer with adhoc network option). Same also for shell command "networksetup". If Apple has decided to put it back recently, you should have a look on man pages of these 2 command with Terminal. but I am afraid not...